# Spring MVC: How to return multiple JSONs, plus other attributes, in single controller method?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, marshalling

I am using Spring 3.2 and Spring MVC.  Jackson libraries are included in my setup.

I have a page which, on initial load, needs to populate two data sources for Dojo dropdown boxes (data sources are Strings in the JSON format) and two textboxes.  I am assuming I can add these to the Model as four Strings before returning.

I find plenty of examples where a controller with a method annotated with @ResponseBody returns a single JSON in response to an AJAX request, but I can't find any examples of how to handle the above situation (which is not a response to an AJAX request, and includes multiple JSONs as well as simple Strings).

1. Is my approach of returning four Strings (two containing JSONs, and
   two containing the textbox contents) in the Model sound?
2. If the answer to (1) above is Yes: How to pull in two List
       objects into the method as JSONs and store them in Strings?

Comment: This statement: _needs to populate two JSONs_, doesn't make sense. Are these text fields, inputs, something else?

Comment: Emended the phrase to be more descriptive.  I mean two datasource strings in the JSON format... used by Dojo on the front end to populate two dropdown boxes.

Comment: Emended the question based on even further research.  The issue is a way to do the equivalent operation that @ResponseBody does (technically, the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter's ObjectMapper) on a couple of objects and store them in the Model as Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the Solution

I found the solution to the second part of my question (#2).  It is rooted in basic use of Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to serialize a `List` object into a `String` containing JSON notation:

---

```
@RequestMapping()
protected String initPage(Model model) {

    List<StateDropDownEntry> states = stateService.getStates();
    List<TownDropDownEntry> towns = townService.getTowns();

    ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String statesJson = objMapper.writeValueAsString(states); // try|catch removed for clarity
    String townsJson = objMapper.writeValueAsString(towns);  

    model.addAttribute("statesJson",statesJson);
    model.addAttribute("townsJson",townsJson);

    return "stateTownQueryPage";
}
```

---

Although, I do acknowledge the alternate approach of architecting the materialization of *those JSONs that are able to be created the first time the page is served* as AJAX calls (just as you would those JSONs that depend on user input after the initial time the page is served) to controller methods which use the `@ResponseBody` annotation.  That approach has its merits also.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the *client* and Spring MVC is the *server*. They are distinct processes, often running on separate machines.

A document in your browser can make as many (AJAX) HTTP requests as it wants to your server.

So, if you want to load a drop-down widget using AJAX, make a request to your server to get the data.

If you want to load another drop-down widget using AJAX, make another request to your server.

Or, to minimize the number of requests, you could

a) Load the data as regular HTML in the first response, and not use AJAX at all

b) Combine the responses in a different controller action, like:

```
{
  dropDown1Data:[...],
  dropDown2Data:[...],
  textBox1Data:[...], ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mention **on initial load**.  You do not need to send json to the page on the initial load.  JSON is for AJAX requests.

To populate controls on the initial load, just put objects into the Model and reference them in on the page.

For example,

```
List blam1 = new ArrayList();
... populate blam1 ...
Model.addAttribute("blam1", blam1);
```

then on the page (JSP in this example)

```
<c:foreach items="blam1" var="current>
Current: ${current}<br/>
</c:foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting multiple input use this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/....", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> functionName(@RequestBody Model model){
    //TODO : Your task
    return response;
}
```